# How do I get the repository defaults in an GitHub organisation?

Tags: github-api

I am planning to create a GitHub app that can auto assign the default labels in a GitHub organisation to previously created repositories. For that, I am looking for an API to get the default labels in a GitHub organisation and I couldn't find any. The APIs available related to labels are all scoped to repositories. I also couldn't find an API that could give or update the default branch in an organisation.

Is such as API available?

Comment: I know about [this section of the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-default-labels-for-repositories-in-your-organization) but it seems to work only for new repositories, not for previously created ones...

Comment: Yep, we were looking into creating a GH Bot which could read these and retroactively add them. But I would need an API to get that data which I am unable to find.